# Get a reference to an object while instantiating it

Tags: ruby

I'd like to reference an object while instantiating it in order to pass it to another object I'm instantiating.  What I mean:

```
A.new(B.new(self))
```

In this case, `self` would refer to the scope in which I'm actually calling `A.new`.  What I want is for `self` (or whatever other keyword) to refer to the newly instantiated `A` object, so that `B` would have a reference to `A`.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: To call it this way would be a circular reference, since the A instance is needed to instantiate B, which is needed for A, etc. You could move the B.new into A#initialize though.

Comment: If you're at this point, there's probably a better design you're not seeing. Try fleshing out your example a little more with some of the example code.

Comment: Will `B.new(A.new)`, not suffice?

Comment: @Rogue @Progfan my understanding is that he wants to be able to call `a.b` and `b.a` - i.e. the objects should both reference one another. This will cause an infinite recursion, but it's perfectly valid: `#<A:0x007f86169bd090 @b=#<B:0x007f86169bd068 @a=#<A:0x007f86169bd090 ...>>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have written it (`A.new(B.new(self))`) is **impossible**, due to a *circular reference*.

In order to create an instance of `A`, you need an instance of `B`; in order to create the instance of `B`, you need the instance of `A`.

There are a few ways you tweak the implementation to make this possible, but you must first resolve this chicken-and-egg problem between the `A` and `B`. For example:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @b = yield(self)
  end
end

class B
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end
end

A.new { |a| B.new(a) }
```

Note that in the above code, `a` is being initialized *first*. It is only being yielded in the scope *after* the object has been created.

Or, here's another way:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @b = B.new(self)
  end
end

class B
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end
end

A.new
```

Like above, the instance of `A` is being created *first*. But this time, I've done all the initialization in one go rather than building it within the `new()` methed call.

One final example:

```
class A
  attr_writer :b
  def initialize
  end
end

class B
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end
end

A.new.tap { |a| a.b = B.new(a) }
```

In this example, I have *fully initialized* `a` before defining its attribute of `b`. This could just as easily have been written in two lines of code, with a regular variable instead of the closure:

```
a = A.new
a.b = B.new(a)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I realized that I had a problem with my design shortly after I posted it.  I solved it like this:

`A.new(B)`

And then within `A`, I initialized `B` like I wanted to.